# UWP package size is ~5 times bigger than Unity3d Build size

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, uwp, hololens

I've created an app in Unity3D for Microsoft Hololens. After building the app in unity I checked the unity editor logs for app size -

```
Textures      5.6 kb     0.0% 
Meshes        5.1 mb     44.6% 
Animations    33.6 kb    0.3% 
Sounds        3.4 mb     29.6% 
Shaders       1.1 mb     9.4% 
Other Assets  1018.9 kb  8.7% 
Levels        110.6 kb   0.9% 
Scripts       601.4 kb   5.1% 
Included DLLs 124.0 kb   1.1% 
File headers  23.9 kb    0.2% 
Complete size 11.4 mb    100.0%
```

Then I opened the resulted package in Visual Studio and followed the build process to build App for Windows Store. After build process succeeded I checked the size of app package -

```
For x86, x64 and ARM architectures -

Appname_1.1.2.0_x86_x64_arm_bundle_Master.appxupload    151 Mb
```

I want to know why there is such a big difference between the Unity3D build size(11.4 mb) and Windows app build package(151 mb) ?? Am I missing something? How can I remove this difference or minimize it??

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the name of the `APPXUPLOAD` file and on the line above, the file contains x86, x64 and ARM packages so it logically has to be at least thrice bigger in size.

Don't worry, Windows Store will download only the required packages when downloading the app e.i. if you'll be downloading it on x64 PC it will download only the x64 package.

Another thing enlarging the file size may be Assets for multiple DPIs - app icons etc. - but Windows Store, once again, downloads only the required files.

Comment: It should be ~3 times bigger, which means 11.4 * 3 = 34.2 mb OR 50 mb at max. But its 151 mb :( Also, my app icons size is 68 *kb*.

Comment: It may be some other things that it includes, I don't know, but you may try downloading it from Windows Store and there you will see how much  space does it take.

Answer (score 0):

It might be extra debugging information in your build.

When generating the app packages under "Select and Configure Packages" untick "Include full PDB symbol files, if any, to enable crash analytics for the app".

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713514/should-i-compile-release-builds-with-debug-info-as-full-or-pdb-only) is some related information from another question.

Comment: I tried building the package by untick "Include full PDB symbol files, if any, to enable crash analytics for the app". The resulting package size was 132mb. Still a big difference.