# gdb : what is a symbol-file used for debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, makefile, gdb

I am badly confused with files generated during compilation and used for debugging.

I know there two ways to store debugging info when compiling a code. One is to store the info in a separate file other than the executable (or object file) normally with a .sym extention)

1- I do not know what is the other method. (and which one is more common to use)

2- what is a symbol file in the first place? (a little more detailed than it keeps debugging info)

3- if we are given a huge source code with its makefiles, how can we figure out which method is used when we do "make install"

I have seen this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919911/what-is-debug-info) but I got even more confused !

Comment: The other method is including debug symbols in the executable itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The other method is including all debugging info in the executable itself.
2. It keeps things such as function names. When a source file is compiled it is translated to opcodes, and all the function names are transformed into pointers. For example when you use gdb you can just `break main` to break on function main. Also it's useful when you've got a segfault, you just type in `bt` and it gives the backtrace with full function names.
3. You can just open the Makefile and search for the install target. Debugging info level is set with the gcc `-g` or `-gN` flag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. from (3) you mean if compilation is done with "-g" flag, then the debugging info is stored in the executable itself?

Comment: Yes, that is the usual method. Google for DWARF debug format. Or do readelf --debug-dump your-binary-file (and check man readelf for selective dump).